# gulp-less seems to be removing @media print query

Tags: css, less, gulp, gulp-less

It seems to be ripped off all my @media print less queries in build steps. Is this a 'gulp-less' bug or am I doing something wrong? I'm new to this build steps.

My gulp task for less

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  gulp.src(['./src/less/app.less', './src/less/responsive.less'])
    .pipe(less({
      paths: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/less'), path.resolve(__dirname, 'bower_components') ]
    }))
    .pipe(mobilizer('app.css', {
      'app.css': {
        hover: 'exclude',
        screens: ['0px']      
      },
      'hover.css': {
        hover: 'only',
        screens: ['0px']
      }
    }))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(config.dest, 'css')));
});
```

**Note** It's not an issue with cssmin. I tried without cssmin() pipe line.

Comment: Possible also add your Less code with the `@media` code. I could not confirm that gulp-less remove any `@media`. What about your mobilizer task?

Comment: Ooops! you are correct. mobilzer is the one who get the blame. Add this as an answer, I'll accept it :)